# How to create sticky full-page vertical lines with CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a React project. I use React-Bootstrap as UI library.

I want to create vertical lines like this, but i want it always visible over the content. How should I write CSS for this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR7sO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a div like this on absolute position

```
<div style="background: red; width:1px; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 100px; top:0"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an  div with length of 100%, width of 2-5px and background-color of your liking.